# Multiprocessing with PyAudio and Tkinter in Python not working on Mac OS X

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, pyaudio

I'm trying to make a GUI application that incorporates both image and audio processing simultaneously using the **multiprocessing** library. However the same code when tested on a Mac OS X does not seem to work, unless I remove the **import tkinter** statement

```
import pyaudio
# The import statement below is causing the problem
import tkinter as tki
import multiprocessing
import threading

def do_task():
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    print("Task complete")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_task, args=())
    p.start()
    # Code works when import statement is placed here
    # import tkinter as tki
    p.join()
```

The above code prints **Task complete** on Windows and also prints **Task complete** when the import statement is shifted, which is not a good solution as I'll need to start the multiprocessing after I initialize the UI.

Is there any workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if we knew what exactly the Error is, so if you could copy it in it would be nice. ^^
Anyways I don't have good experiences with `multiprocessing.Process` either so I use `threading.Thread` instead. Therefor I define a new class with `Thread` as metaclass and define whatever the running function should be as `run`.
e.g.:

```
from threading import Thread

class Audio(Thread):
    def __init__(self,...):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        #...
    def run(self):
        #audio stuff

class GUI(Thread):
    def __init__(self,...):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        #...
    def run(self):
        #GUI stuff
a,g=Audio(),GUI()
a.start(),g.start()
```

I don't know if that really helps but I hope so. :D